# WinRT GetSystemIdForPublisher() unable to execute due to C++20 coroutines?

Tags: c++

I am trying to get the system ID using

```
auto info = winrt::Windows::System::Profile::SystemIdentification::GetSystemIdForPublisher();
auto id = info.Id();
auto asHex = winrt::Windows::Security::Cryptography::CryptographicBuffer::EncodeToHexString(id);
```

But when I try to run this code I get errors `E0035` and `C1189` and both have the exact same description:

> The <experimental/coroutine> and <experimental/resumable> headers are only supported with /await and implement pre-C++20 coroutine support. Use *coroutine* for standard C++20 coroutines.

(Note: the italic *coroutine* above is inside <>, as soon as I put <> around the a word it disappears so I have omitted it)

I am including all the relevant files in my header that I think might be needed:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <coroutine>
#include <windows.foundation.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.System.Profile.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Security.Cryptography.h>
```

I am using:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019
Microsoft Visual C++ 2019
Windows 10 SDK 10.0.19041.0
```

Comment: You are using a very old version of C++/WinRT that predates C++20. 19041 was released at the start of 2020, and C++20 wasn't ratified until September 2020. Upgrade to [a newer version of C++/WinRT](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.CppWinRT/).

Comment: @RaymondChen Thank you! I installed the new version of C++/WinRT from the link provided by you and it works. I also updated to Windows 11 SDK (10.0.22000.0) and with this, it also works.

Answer (score 0):

In your project, if you go to

1. Property Pages ->
2. Configuration Properties ->
3. General ->
4. C++ Language Standard,

do you by any chance have it set to "ISO C++20 Standard (/std:c++20)"?
C++/WinRT only runs C++17.

A few hours ago I realized that C++/WinRT exists, and I am currently trying understand the fundamentals of it. If my memory serves me correctly, I also got this exact error message when trying some not-at-all-copy-pasted-from-msdn code out. Although I am using Visual Studio 2022 (Community Edition), I do not see why that would make a difference.

I hope this is of any use.

Kind regards,
a not so experienced programmer